# Convert Oracle to T-SQL to get total views per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to migrate some Oracle queries to T-SQL due to a migration that I am planning. The following ORACLE query should display the total monthly visits (views) of a web platform I am using.

Obviously `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` are not supported in SQL as they are in Oracle. Instead I have tried using `CONVERT` and `CAST` functions.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (VISIT_TIME,'YYYY.MM') as mydate, count (*) as visits 
FROM AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY 
INNER JOIN user_mapping ON AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY.USER_KEY = user_mapping.USER_KEY 
WHERE lower_username not in ('admin') 
AND VISIT_TIME > to_date( '30/04/2018 23-50-00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24-MI-SS' ) 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (VISIT_TIME,'YYYY.MM') 
ORDER BY TO_CHAR (VISIT_TIME,'YYYY.MM')
```

The output should be a table with months(`YYYY.MM` format) and the total amount of views per month. The oracle query works like a charm but i cannot manage the TSQL query to properly provide the desired outcome. The `VISIT_TIME` column stores the date/time in the following format: `2018-04-19 17:45:24.820` while the `USER_KEY` is mapped with the user_mapping table to get the actual username.

Comment: Have a look at `CONVERT` and it's [Date and Time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles), then show your T-SQL if it doesn't return the result you are after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions.  The following is close:

```
SELECT YEAR(VISIT_TIME), MONTH(VISIT_TIME), COUNT(*) as visits 
FROM AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY ve INNER JOIN
     user_mapping um
     ON ve.USER_KEY = um.USER_KEY 
WHERE lower_username not in ('admin') AND
      VISIT_TIME > '2018-04-03 23:50:00'
GROUP BY YEAR(VISIT_TIME), MONTH(VISIT_TIME) 
ORDER BY YEAR(VISIT_TIME), MONTH(VISIT_TIME);
```

For the exact equivalent, you can use `FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(VISIT_TIME, 'yyyy.MM') as yyyymm, COUNT(*) as visits 
FROM AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY ve INNER JOIN
     user_mapping um
     ON ve.USER_KEY = um.USER_KEY 
WHERE lower_username not in ('admin') AND
      VISIT_TIME > '2018-04-03 23:50:00'
GROUP BY FORMAT(VISIT_TIME, 'yyyy.MM') 
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

I have trouble calling a string column formatted as YYYY.MM anything related to a date, so I've called it yyyymm.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a combination of `replace` and `convert`:

```
-- convert style 23 returns yyyy-mm-dd - take only the first 7 chars and replace the '-' with '.'
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(char(7) VISIT_TIME, 23), '-','.') as mydate, count (*) as visits 
FROM AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY 
INNER JOIN user_mapping 
    ON AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY.USER_KEY = user_mapping.USER_KEY 
WHERE lower_username not in ('admin') 
AND VISIT_TIME > '2018-04-30T25:50:00' -- Always use ISO8601 as datetime format for string literals
GROUP BY REPLACE(CONVERT(char(6) VISIT_TIME, 23), '-','.')
ORDER BY mydate -- the order by clause can use the aliases in the select clause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `CONVERT` and SQL Server [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles).  Here we're using style **102** which displays as `yyyy.MM.dd` and we use `CHAR(7)` 
 to only take the first 7 characters giving `yyyy.MM`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(7), VISIT_TIME, 102) as mydate, count (*) as visits 
FROM AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY 
INNER JOIN user_mapping ON AO_05769A_VISIT_ENTITY.USER_KEY = user_mapping.USER_KEY 
WHERE lower_username not in ('admin') 
AND VISIT_TIME > '2018-04-30 23:50:00' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(7), VISIT_TIME, 102) 
ORDER BY mydate
```